# How to import specific version of jquery and jquery plugins specific only to a certain component in angular5?

Tags: angular

In my app, in angular-cli, the jquery files imported are:

- `jquery.3.3.1`
- `select2.4.0.3`

Those are the versions used globally by other components.

But i have this one component, that uses a specific jquery plugin exclusive only for this component and not used anywhere else that requires
a `jquery.2.2.*` and `select2-3.5.4`.

My question is, how can i use those specific versions exclusive to particular component only.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery can included in the corresponding component_name.component.html

For instance, in my case I included
 
inside my imageslider.component.html

Comment: yup, i've tried this approach already, but in my case, i also need another version of the select2 jquery plugin attached on this jquery instance not just imported jquery for this component.